# (Facebook Login Implementation - Android) Generating invalid Key Hashs for both 'debug' and 'release' environments, how to fix this?

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I would like to share that I wasn't able to find on StackOverflow. I will be sharing what I have done so far and the respective output which I have never faced before.

**What I have done:**

1. Followed the FB login implementation doc and added my LoginActivity for default deep link transactions from Facebook SDK.
2. I created the debug key hash and getting unusual hash-key from the CLI like the image below. In the image you may see there, `=` is missing. [image: generating the debug hash]
3. I am not able to use this key hash while implementing the login API of Facebook. It says the key-hash must end with an `=` character. Ref: in this image below.
    [image]

And the same thing is happening with my `release` hash key. So how can I get rid of this kind of problem?

Comment: I can see someone put a down vote on my question. Please explain what is wrong with this question? I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

if you have ssl executor then try this

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey
-keystore "$PATH\debug.keystore" | "$OPENSSL_PATH\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"$OPENSSL_PATH\bin\openssl" base64
}
```

### Alternative:

### Step 1

go to http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php

### Step 2

paste the SHA-1 in the first field

### Step 3

copy the text in input field under "Output (base64)"

### Step 4

now open developer.facebook.com/apps
click your app
on the left side navigate to "Settings" -> "Basic"
past the Base64 text here under key hashes

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, it worked. But can you explain why it's not working using CLI? @Ranjeet Luhar

Comment: Because your Keyhash didn't converted base64 correctly and facebook SDK accept hash in base64. Using CLI command you need OPENSSL executor if you didn't have installed or in your local system then CLI will return you directly hash.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not convinced with your explanation. If I don't have OPENSSL executor, how can I execute the CLI command in the first place? and generating hash which doesn't have trailing ```=```. Anyways, I had the OPENSSL and set that globally using the environment variable. Thanks for your omment

Comment: SSL base64 conversion is not happening in right way. I think. If you satisfy with answer kindly upvote or mark it so, it can help others too

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fastest way to get SHA-1 key. Please follow below steps.

1. Open Android Studio
2. Open your Project
3. Click on Gradle (From Right Side Panel, you will see Gradle Bar)
4. Click on Refresh (Click on Refresh from Gradle Bar, you will see List Gradle scripts of your Project)
5. Click on Your Project (Your Project Name form List (root))
6. Click on Tasks
7. Click on Android
8. Double Click on signingReport (You will get SHA1 and MD5 in Run Bar(Sometimes it will be in Gradle Console))

**Example**

[image]
Select app module from module selection dropdown to run or debug your application

And then call following function in onCreate of your activity

or

In App following code to generate hash key. And then run your app you can check you hash key in logcat.

```
fun generateHashKey(context: Context){
    try {
        val info = context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES)
        for (signature in info.signatures) {
            val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA")
            md.update(signature.toByteArray())
            val hashKey = String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(md.digest()))
            Log.i("AppLog", "key:$hashKey=")
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("AppLog", "error:", e)
    }

}
```